# Convert type object column to float

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a table with a column named "price". This column is of type object. So, it contains numbers as strings and also NaN or ? characters. I want to find the mean of this column but first I have to remove the NaN and ? values and also convert it to float

I am using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('Automobile_data.csv', sep = ',')

df = df.dropna('price', inplace=True)
df['price'] = df['price'].astype('int')
df['price'].mean()
```

But, this doesn't work. The error says:

```
ValueError: No axis named price for object type DataFrame
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try df = df.dropna(subset='price', inplace=True), it's reading 'price' as the axis parameter at the moment

Comment: @CharlieBONS Now it says: "TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'price' was passed"

Answer (score 0):

edit: in pandas version 1.3 and less, you need `subset=[col]` wrapped in a list/array. In verison 1.4 and greater you can pass a single column as a string.

You've got a few problems:

1. `df.dropna()` arguments require the axis and then the subset. The axis is rows/columns, and then subset is which of those to look at. So you want this to be (I think) `df.dropna(axis='rows',subset='price')`
2. Using `inplace=True` makes the whole thing return `None`, and so you have set `df = None`. You don't want to do that. If you are using `inplace=True`, then you don't assign something to that, the whole line would just be `df.dropna(...,inplace=True)`.
3. Don't use `inplace=True`, just do the assignment. That is, you **should** use `df=df.dropna(axis='rows',subset='price')`

Comment: I still receive a TypeError:  Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'price' was passed

Comment: what line of code is giving you that error? and does your dataframe actually have a column called 'price'? You can check by reading it and then doing a `print(df.columns)`

Comment: The price is a column and this column has "?" characters and numbers as strings

Comment: These are the columns:   Index(['symboling', 'normalized-losses', 'make', 'fuel-type', 'aspiration',
       'num-of-doors', 'body-style', 'drive-wheels', 'engine-location',
       'wheel-base', 'length', 'width', 'height', 'curb-weight', 'engine-type',
       'num-of-cylinders', 'engine-size', 'fuel-system', 'bore', 'stroke',
       'compression-ratio', 'horsepower', 'peak-rpm', 'city-mpg',
       'highway-mpg', 'price'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: what line of code gives you the error?

Comment: So, just by writing the line that you said it gave me the error. Note that I'm using jupyter lab

Comment: try `subset=['price']`. In pandas v1.3 and less, the subset needs to be array-like, but in v1.4 and greater you can pass a single string.